# Google Spreadsheet API If-Match does not take affect

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

It appears passing the etag in the HTTP header If-Match, does not do anything the the case of row delete. This is what I tried:

```
curl --silent -X GET --header "GData-Version: 3.0" --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$TOKEN" https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxx/od6/private/full/cokwr | tidy -xml -indent -quiet | egrep "etag|title"
gd:etag='"YGdaHlAXHyt7Ig.."'>
  <title>TEST1</title>

Changed the cell. (The etag changed)

curl --silent -X GET --header "GData-Version: 3.0" --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$TOKEN" https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxx/od6/private/full/cokwr | tidy -xml -indent -quiet | egrep "etag|title"
gd:etag='"agoUURMYXyt7ImA."'>
  <title>TEST1-new</title>

curl --silent -X DELETE --header 'If-Match: "YGdaHlAXHyt7Ig.."' --header "GData-Version: 3.0" --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$TOKEN" https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/xxx/od6/private/full/cokwr | tidy -xml -indent -quiet

(The row got deleted)
```

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1#deleting_a_list_row